# Equality operator in java double not working as intended

Tags: java, double

I wrote a program which i suppose should print true , Instead its giving false as out put.

```
  public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    double i = 0.0 / 0.0;
    System.out.println(i - i == 0);
 }
}
```

Can some one explain me why it is behaving so .

Comment: because nothing equals `NaN`

Comment: your marking your own question duplicate ?

Comment: Yeah i found this ..duplicate after googling it.

Answer (score 2):

It is because `i = 0.0 / 0.0` is equal to `NaN`, so `NaN` neither equal to `0` nor to it self `(Nan)`

Comment: Also, note that NaN isn't even equal to itself.

Comment: Perhaps phrase it as "`i = 0.0 / 0.0` results in a NaN"? It cannot be "equal to `NaN`" because **nothing** is equal to `NaN`.

Answer (score 1):

This is because :

```
public class TestClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    double i = 0.0 / 0.0;
    System.out.println(i-i); //NaN
    System.out.println(i - i == 0);//false
 }
}
```

`NaN`, standing for not a number, is a numeric data type value representing an undefined or unrepresentable value, especially in floating-point calculations.

Answer (score 0):

```
double i = 0.0 / 0.0; // this assigned i=NaN
```

> "NaN" stands for "not a number". "Nan" is produced if a floating point operation has some input parameters that cause the operation to produce some undefined result. For example, 0.0 divided by 0.0 is arithmetically undefined. Taking the square root of a negative number is also undefined.

when you compare

```
 System.out.println(i - i == 0); // it do Nan-Nan which is NaN
```

It try to compare

```
 NaN to 0 which is false
```

[Java Floating Points](http://www.ica.luz.ve/dfinol/mat/javafloat.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
double i = 0.0 / 0.0;
```

It will evaluate to `NaN`

And `i - i` will be `NaN - NaN` Which is again `NaN` i.e. `!= 0`

Answer (score 0):

What were you expecting? `0.0 / 0.0` is an [indeterminate form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form), which is mapped with a special value according to floating format which is [`NaN`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN).

It's a special value because it's destructive, it propagates through each successive arithmetic operation, and that's good because it helps diagnosing problems with operations.

Indeed that's the case `0.0 / 0.0 = NaN` and `NaN - whatever = NaN` (so `(0.0/0.0)-5.0` yields `NaN` too).